# EC2 instance with a cross account IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've created a cross account IAM role in one of my accounts(say account A) and would like to attach that role to an ec2 instance in another account(account B).

I tried creating a new role in account B with sts:AssumeRole pointing to the role in A and attached it to an ec2 instance in B. Doesn't seem to be working.

How can the ec2 instance assume the cross account role in A?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot attach a cross-account IAM role to an EC2 instance directly. And having the `sts:AssumeRole` permissions does not automatically make the one role assume into the other.

Instead:

1. Create your cross-account role in Account A.
2. Create an IAM role for EC2 instances in Account B. Give this role permissions to execute `sts:AssumeRole`.
3. Assign the IAM role from #2 to your EC2 instance.

Then, when you want to access the AWS API from your EC2 instance:

1. Execute `sts:AssumeRole` to assume the cross-account role for Account A, to obtain temporary credentials.
2. Use those temporary credentials to execute the rest of your API methods.

Answer (score 14):

Supposing the scenario with two accounts A & B the explanatory steps should be:

1. In **account A**, I created a **role** (e.g `RoleForB`) to trust **account B**, and attach to the before created role a **IAM policy** to allow it to perform some read operations in **account A**. `e.g ReadOnlyAccess`
2. In **account B**, I created a **role** (e.g `AssumeRoleInA`) and attach a **policy** to allow it to assume the role that is created in **account A**.
3. In **account B** Associate to your EC2 instance `ec2-profile` the IAM role (`AssumeRoleInA`) created in step 2.
4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`.
5. In **account B** EC2 terminal when the command is **step 4.** finished, you can see the **access key ID, secret access key, and session token** from wherever you've routed it, in our case `stdout` either manually or by using a script. You can then assign these values to environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`)

So Let’s check the configurations mentioned above step by step but with some mode detail:

1. As before presented in **account A**, it builds the trust to **account B** by creating the role named `RoleForB` and attaching `ReadOnlyAccess` permission to it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:root"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

2. In **account B**, create a **role** named `AssumeRoleInA` then attach the corresponding `policy` to allow it to assume the role named `RoleForB` in **account A**.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. In **account B**, create a new **EC2 instance** (if it does not exists yet), and associate it's **ec2-profile** with the **IAM role** named `AssumeRoleInA`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`
```

eg:

```
jenkins@bb-jenkins-vault:~$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::521111111144:role/DeployMaster --role-session-name "project-dev-jenkins-deploy"
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROAJBXGEHOQBXGEHOQ:project-dev-jenkins-deploy", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::521111111144:assumed-role/DeployMaster/project-dev-jenkins-deploy"
    }, 
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY", 
        "SessionToken": "FQoGZXIvYXCUm8iG6/zLdQ7foognvCDpxKP7cRJiZgc...CUm8iG6/zLdQ7foognvCDpxKP7c+OQF", 
        "Expiration": "2019-03-29T15:41:02Z", 
        "AccessKeyId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE"
    }
}
```

5. In **account B** EC2 terminal when the command is **step 4.** finished, you can see the **access key ID, secret access key, and session token** from wherever you've routed it, in our case `stdout` either manually or by using a script. You can then assign these values to environment variables

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
$ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=FQoGZXIvYXCUm8iG6/zLdQ...<remainder of security token>
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

**complementary reading:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

Comment: Worked like a charm! I followed it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export as below for step 5 above :

```
TEMP_ACCESS_ACCOUNT=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB --role-session-name example)

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo ${TEMP_ACCESS_ACCOUNT} | jq -r '.["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"]')

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo ${TEMP_ACCESS_ACCOUNT} | jq -r '.["Credentials"]["SecretAccessKey"]')

export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo ${TEMP_ACCESS_ACCOUNT} | jq -r '.["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]')
```

Comment: could you explanation on wha this is doing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html), you can create a named role profile in `~/.aws/config`, on your EC2 instance in ACCOUNT B, as follows

```
[profile marketingadmin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/marketingadminrole
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

The following might be useful for similar scenarios

> The credential_source attribute supports the following values:
>
> - Environment – Retrieves the source credentials from environment variables.
> - Ec2InstanceMetadata – Uses the IAM role attached to the Amazon EC2 > instance profile.
> - EcsContainer – Uses the IAM role attached to the Amazon ECS container.